# firestore document snapshot get() does not work with dotted string notation of field-names containing hyphen

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I've a simple document called 'agents' under a collection named 'mycoll' with data set something like below:

```
{
 'metadata': {
   'agent-ids': ['fdfd', 'asdfasdf', 'rerere'],
   'agent_ids': ['foo1', 'booo']
}
```

I got the document snapshot:

```
snapshot = firestore.client().document('mycoll/agents').get()
```

If I try to access 'agent-ids' field name using get() method on this snapshot:

```
agent-list-with-hypens = snapshot.get('metadata.agent-ids')
```

> ValueError: Path metadata.agent-ids not consumed, residue: -ids

However, If I try to access 'agent_ids' using get() method, that works just  fine:

```
print(snapshot.get('metadata.agent_ids'))
```

> ['foo1', 'booo']

My question is what is causing this different behavior for field-names with an '-' and why? Any documentation which explains about this? I understand that snapshot.get() accpets a FieldPath argument instead of plain string but existing API documentation does not warn that field-names with an '-' are not allowed in field-path name strings delimited by '.'
In fact, `snapshot.get(firestore.client().field_path('metadata', 'agent-ids'))` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas), here are  the constraints on field paths:

- Must separate field names with a single period (.)
- Must enclose each field name in backticks unless the field name meets the following requirements:

  - The field name contains only the characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and underscore (_)
  - The field name does not start with 0-9

So a field name/path containing dash will raise **ValueError**. The above constraints also explain why `snapshot.get(firestore.client().field_path('metadata', 'agent-ids'))` works just fine is because the field name is enclosed in backticks.